# What Should Sorting In My Controller Look Like?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a Spring controller for my REST API that currently allows searching by various parameters:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/dogs", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<DogDTO>> getDogs(
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer page,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
  @RequestParam(required = false) String colour,
  @RequestParam(required = false) String breed,
  @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
```

e.g. `/api/dogs?colour=black&breed=labrador`

The response is currently displayed in a table but now there is a requirement to search asc or desc on any of these columns - but not on more than one at the same time.

How should I change my controller definition to add sorting on these parameters and specify asc and dec?
and what would the url look like after these changes?

e.g.

```
/api/dogs?colour=black?sort=-id
/api/dogs?colour=black?sort=id&dir=asc
```

Answer (score -1):

you are correct you have to add 2 more parameters sort and dir, If you follow the same logic.

```
@RequestParam(required = false) String sort
@RequestParam(required = false) String dir
```

> /api/dogs?colour=black&sort=column&dir=asc

In your DAO modify your query and add

> select column from table order by column asc;

Comment: You can get away with one param -- `dir` -- if it exists then a sort is required, otherwise not.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer please share the code, how to achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: It's not that hard, I'm sure you can work it out. Something like, `sort=-id` or `sort=+id` indicating that it should sort on the dir column ascending or descending depending on the column and sign. If the request param is null (doesn't exist) then don't sort.

Comment: Why it's -1  please explain what is wrong in it ? Thank you

Comment: It's a convention, that's all. -ve for descending, +ve for ascending. Your code could treat it either way. The UI simply has an element with a click handler that toggles between +ve and -ve column names, and your backend code interprets that as instructions to sort the given column ascending or descending. It really isn't that complicated, and you really only need one param.

Comment: And, comments aren't meant for extended discussons.

Comment: you only extended it and not provided exact solution, Happy downgrading others helps !! anyway I understood your solution and not commented further.